# Open a dialog on doubleclick in a TableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a TableViewer with a few columns. The content of some fields is much
to long for the field. Therefor I would like to open a dialog when the user
double clicks on the field.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `MouseEvent` to capture the event. And then use

```
if (e.getClickCount() == 2) { // MouseEvent e in the parameter.
  // show the dialoge
}
```

Comment: I have tried as follows.but  text was not displayed.      tableViewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.BORDER); 
 tableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {         
           public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
           
           StructuredSelection selection = (StructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
           selection.getFirstElement().getClass().getName();
          
            
            
           
           MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(),"",selection.getFirstElement().toString());
          
           }
           });